# Are there alternatives to Backbone.js to help synchronizing frontend data with the backend?

Tags: javascript, ajax, backbone.js

I have a full-ajax web application and I want to keep the data synced with the database. I have implemented a RESTful API on the backend, but if needed additional functionality may be implemented. It will be collaborative application so data can change frequently. Data should be updated frequently (for example 30s intervals).

I started doing the frontend with only jQuery but I then realized there must be some libraries to help syncing with the backend. I found that Backbone.js has a [sync feature](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Sync) that is similar to what I am looking. But before I start I thought to ask if there are any other javascript libraries with features to help synchronizing the data easily.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this [nettuts comparison of 20 frameworks](http://net.tutsplus.com/articles/web-roundups/20-javascript-frameworks-worth-checking-out/)

though personally I recommend you the backbone - it's very agile and fast to learn + leaves you with a lot of freedom and happiness :)

But imo the special thing about the backbone compared to others is the community - and no fancy feature can replace that!